# How to use alias in JPA Criteria API in FROM and SELECT clause in Java?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

My current code generates native sql like this:

```sql
select ebillorder0_.ID as id1_3_, 
from COMORC_NUTE_EBILL_ORDERS ebillorder0_ 
inner join COMORC_NUTE_EBILL_CUSTOMER ebillcusto1_ on ebillorder0_.EBILL_CUSTOMER=ebillcusto1_.ID 
where ebillorder0_.ORDER_TYPE=? and ebillorder0_.ORDER_STATUS=? and ebillcusto1_.CHANNEL=? and (ebillorder0_.LANGUAGE not in  (?))
```

In `from`, `where` and `select` clauses I would like to use some predefined alias. That is, I need my code to generates something like this:

```sql
select myOrder.ID as id1_3_, 
from COMORC_NUTE_EBILL_ORDERS myOrder
inner join COMORC_NUTE_EBILL_CUSTOMER ebillcusto1_ on myOrder.EBILL_CUSTOMER=ebillcusto1_.ID 
where myOrder.ORDER_TYPE=? and myOrder.ORDER_STATUS=? and ebillcusto1_.CHANNEL=? and (myOrder.LANGUAGE not in  (?))
```

The code that generates first described query is like so:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EbillOrder> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EbillOrder.class);
Root<EbillOrder> ebillOrderRoot = (Root<EbillOrder>) criteriaQuery.from(EbillOrder.class);
Join<EbillOrder, EbillCustomer> customerJoin = ebillOrderRoot.join("ebillCustomer");

criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(ebillOrderRoot.get("id")).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

        Query innerQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        String innerQuerySql = com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.SQLExtractor.from(innerQuery);
```

I have tried many things, but this is most relevant I have got:

```
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select((Selection) ebillOrderRoot.get("id").alias("myOrder")).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Relation between Batch and Order is 1-1.

Comment: Why do you need to change the aliases or why do you even care about them?

Comment: It is quite complex to explain why :) In summary I'm building dynamic native sql query in which I have to use Oracle's `row_function()` with `over` keyword. In `over` I'm referencing alias in `from` clause. So I need to be able to set my custom alias.

Comment: You need raw SQL here.

Comment: You're positive that I cannot predefine those aliases programmatically?

Comment: There is a design problem here.  If you need to use Oracle's analytic functions, then I would say that absolutely you should be using a native query, or possibly a prepared stored proc, but not CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: Native query is used at the end but this subquery is generated programmatically using CriteriaAPI, once I generate query I insert at appropriate place this: `, row_number() over(ORDER BY ebillorder0_.CREATION_TIME) row_number_ ` Then I run: `Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());`

Comment: I manually set 'ebillorder0_.CREATION_TIME' but I want that ebillorder0_ to be set as myOrder

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here, maybe you could share the SQL you want to execute?
Either way, usually you can try to use a custom `SQLFunction` for this purpose. This is a Hibernate contract that allows you to render custom SQL fragments for a function in HQL/Criteria.

E.g. you can write something like this:

```sql
from MyEntity e
where my_function(e.id) = 1
```

and the `SQLFunction` that you register under the name `my_function` can render a SQL fragment of your choice.